# SQL - Aggregate and Group by

Tags: sql

I am trying to break out email types into separate columns in a SQL query. I want a column for Home, another for work, and another for alternate. I have all kinds of combinations. I put comments in my work logic, home is much the same. I am having two problems.

1. If I don't include . A07.EmailAddress ,A07.Active,A07.EmailType, A07.UseAsPrimary in my code it throws the error 'is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' but if I include it, it does not count the emails correctly
2. I need to identify the alternate as the leftover ones in home. The logic would be that there was a valid home one in the home case and this is a second one. By definition it would have to be on accounts with multiple home emails and one already identified in the first case.

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT 

    A01.RecordId
    ,a01.AccountNumber
    ,A01.FamilyId
    ,case  
        when A01.OrganizationName IS NULL OR Len(A01.OrganizationName) = 0  
        then A01.FirstName + ' ' + A01.LastName
        else A01.OrganizationName
            end as 'Name'
    , case 
        when (A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'WORK' 
            AND ((sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'WORK' then 1 else null end) = 1) --- there is only one work email
            OR (sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'WORK' then 1 else null end) > 1 and A07.UseAsPrimary = 1) --- multiple work emails but one is marked primary
                )
              )
        then A07.EmailAddress
        when A07.EmailType = 'WORK' then A07.EmailAddress --- one work email but not marked primary
        end as 'Work Email'
    ,case
       when (A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'HOME' 
            AND ((sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then 1 else null end) = 1)
            OR (sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then 1 else null end) > 1 and A07.UseAsPrimary = 1)
                )
              )
        then A07.EmailAddress
        when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then A07.EmailAddress
        end as 'Home Email'
        ----------------
    , case
       when (A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'HOME' 
            AND ((sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then 1 else null end) > 1 
                and  A07.UseAsPrimary <> 1)
                )
              )
        then A07.EmailAddress
        --when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then A07.EmailAddress
        end as 'Alternate Email'

  FROM A01_ACCOUNTMASTER A01
  left JOIN [dbo].[A07_AccountEmails] A07 on A01.AccountNumber = A07.AccountNumber

  where 
    A01.[Status] = 'A'
  group by A01.AccountNumber, a01.RecordId, A01.FamilyId, A01.OrganizationName, A01.FirstName, A01.LastName
  --, A07.EmailAddress ,A07.Active,A07.EmailType, A07.UseAsPrimary
```

Comment: Change `sum` by subqueries or use `sum() over partition`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using window function `sum() over partition`

Not tested:

```
SELECT distinct -- replaced group by with distinct
  A01.RecordId,a01.AccountNumber,A01.FamilyId
 ,case  
    when A01.OrganizationName IS NULL OR Len(A01.OrganizationName) = 0  
      then A01.FirstName + ' ' + A01.LastName
    else A01.OrganizationName
  end as 'Name'
 ,case 
    when (
      A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'WORK' 
      AND (
        (sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'WORK' then 1 else null end) over partition by (A01.AccountNumber)= 1) --- there is only one work email
        OR 
        (sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'WORK' then 1 else null end) over partition by (A01.AccountNumber)> 1 and A07.UseAsPrimary = 1) --- multiple work emails but one is marked primary
      )
    )
      then A07.EmailAddress
    when A07.EmailType = 'WORK' then A07.EmailAddress --- one work email but not marked primary
  end as 'Work Email'
 ,case
    when (
      A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'HOME' 
      AND (
        (sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then 1 else null end) over partition by (A01.AccountNumber) = 1)
        OR 
        (sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then 1 else null end) over partition by (A01.AccountNumber) > 1 and A07.UseAsPrimary = 1)
      )
    )
      then A07.EmailAddress
    when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then A07.EmailAddress
  end as 'Home Email'
  ----------------
 ,case
    when (
      A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'HOME' 
      AND sum(case when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then 1 else null end) over partition by (A01.AccountNumber) > 1 
      and  A07.UseAsPrimary <> 1
    )
      then A07.EmailAddress
    --when A07.EmailType = 'HOME' then A07.EmailAddress
  end as 'Alternate Email'
FROM A01_ACCOUNTMASTER A01
  left JOIN [dbo].[A07_AccountEmails] A07 on A01.AccountNumber = A07.AccountNumber
  where A01.[Status] = 'A'
  -- group by A01.AccountNumber, a01.RecordId, A01.FamilyId, A01.OrganizationName, A01.FirstName, A01.LastName
  --, A07.EmailAddress ,A07.Active,A07.EmailType, A07.UseAsPrimary
```

Comment: Almost there! 'over (partition by A01.AccountNumber)' worked in that the error is gone and its capturing correctly, but it is still giving me a separate line for the alternate email vs. the home email. Any way to get them on the same line?